# How to drop Angular into an existing .net MVC project

Tags: c#, .net, angular

So, I'm working on a project using the .net MVC framework, and we'd like to use Angular for the frontend. Our project is structured as follows:
    /Areas
    /ClientApp
    /Controllers
    /Data
    /Dto
    /Models
    /Services
    /ViewModels
    /Views

It's pretty boiler-plate, and it's auto-generated from Visual Studio.

I'm attempting to add in Angular. I ran ng new and generated the ClientApp directory shown above.

However, when running the app and accessing the home page, I still end up running through Controllers/HomeController and the accompanying Views/Home/Index.cshtml.

We want to keep the controllers for future API work. We have no interest at all in keeping the Views directory.

So, how can I have my project actually use that Angular directory? What's the proper way to structure this thing?

By the way, startup.cs looks like this:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<Models.ApplicationUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddUserManager<Services.ApplicationUserManager>();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            services.AddMvc()
                .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                });

            // Add project services.
            services.AddSingleton(_ => Configuration); // enables us to inject IConfigurationRoot into service layer class.
            // other choices: services.AddScoped, services.AddTransient
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "areas",
                  template: "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );
            });
        }
```

Comment: The easiest way would be to add a script tag to the angular app in the Views/Home/Index.cshtml and initialize the angular app on this page. I know you said you have no interest in keeping the Views folder, hence the comment and not answer.... If you want to do it properly, develop the angular app outside the mvc app and hit the mvc app api's from the angular app (web api)

Comment: Actually, that sounds like a really great way to do what I want to do. I'm fine keeping Views. I'm just not tied to it.